# Enabling fastscroll from a ListActivity with a simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, listactivity, simplecursoradapter, fastscroll

I know you can set fastScroll for listViews, but currently I would like to use a ListActivity with a simplecursoradapter instead. Is there a way to make such a view fast scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what kind of cursor you use. Just set `android:fastScrollEnabled` in your layout XML file, or call `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` in code if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing this.setFastScrollEnabled(true) in the ListActivity itself, but that method is not defined for ListActivity. What exactly did you have in mind for doing it in code?

Comment: Well, you need to get the ListView through `getListView()`. But you should have an XML layout file too where you can specify android:fastScrollEnabled as well.

Comment: I see. Missed the getListView() method. Thanks!